# How to listen upgrade event after reconnect in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I use Socket.IO.
My client side code is here.

```
socket.io.engine.on("upgrade", () => {
    console.log("upgraded")
})

socket.on("reconnect", () => {
    console.log("reconnected")
})

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("disconnected")
})
```

And,

1. start the server
2. open the page
3. restart the server

console shows

```
upgraded
disconnected
reconnected
```

There is no 'upgraded' after 'reconnected'.

I think that socket.io do upgrade again after reconnect because there are xhr requests before a websocket request.
Also, `socket.io.engine.transport.query.transport` shows 'polling' when reconnect event is occurred, and it becomes 'websocket' in few seconds later.

Can I detect second upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

It worked.

```
const onUpgrade = () => {
    console.log("upgrade")
}

socket.io.engine.on("upgrade", onUpgrade)

socket.on("reconnect", () => {
    console.log("reconnected")
    socket.io.engine.on("upgrade", onUpgrade)
})

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("disconnected")
})
```

`socket.io.engine` differs before and after reconnection.